# How to access external hard drive from within home Wi-Fi?

Tags: external-hard-drive, home-networking

I have a 3TB WD "My Book" and I want to use it as home file storage.

At home I have 2 laptops + 1 10inch netbook.

What are the best ways to share this drive within a Wi-Fi network?

Some kind of old PC server on Debian or Lubuntu? Or are there other means?

**UPDATE 1**

If I understood correctly to avoid server thing, I would need some kind of usb to lan or usb to wifi adapter.

**UPDATE 2**
I found out that there are some usb to ethernet adapters, but they are generally expensive solutions to go with %)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like almost every Wi-Fi home gateway router has a USB port for drive (and printer) sharing nowadays. Your home gateway router / Wi-Fi AP is going to be on all the time anyway, may as well have it act as your NAS device rather than waste power making some other laptop or device be on all the time to serve the same role.

Comment: Unfortunately, my WI-FI router doesn't have any USB %) Nevertheless it might be reasonable to find some module or extensioning device %)

Comment: Or it might be reasonable to replace your router. You need to turn your drive into a NAS and the router is a reasonable place to do this since it is always on. Craigslist can be a good resource in the US.